# Why are there no hubs for the new USB Type-C Port?

Tags: usb

I'm assuming there is some sort of technical limitation. Why is it that all the usb-c hubs are passthrough single usb ports instead of a USB Type-C multiple port hub?

Comment: Didn't quite understand your question, does this qualify as a usb type-C multiple port hub? http://www.nonda.co/products/usb-c-hub-for-apple-new-macbook-12-plus

Comment: @VicJang - its not a true usb-c hub because it only passes the signal through, it does not offer the ability to plug in to usb-c type connections to one port.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a question that is very unpopular.  You're right, but you're not supposed to say it.

Yes, the hub someone wrote about has two USB-C ports out of it, but they will be compromised.

What the problems is - how the USB-C lines within a cable are used is determined at plug-in time, depending on what you plug in downstream of the port.  For example, you can't have full speed USB 3.1 and full video at the same time.  So the USB-C makes a choice for you.  If you plug in both a high-res monitior and USB 3, then you can't have both at once.

So it will be interesting to see how the various hub supplies will handle this problem.

People think that a hub will be much like a USB 3.1 hub, where the function of USB doesn't change when you plug things into it.

But if you plug a high-res monitor into a USB-C hub, your USB regular data will suddenly drop down in speed to what two interior wires can handle, instead of four.  The bandwidth just isn't there.  Today's USB-C is USB-C on training wheels.